# Cache-control and Rails localizations: good practice?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, caching, localization

I have this Rails app that serves a bunch of localized static pages (through a PagesController). The locale is set from the user's `HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE` variable. Problem is, the URL stays the same regardless of the locale, so I can't use `Cache-Control` since it's going to cache the locale as well.

I have read that it is bad practice to not have the locale in the URL. But looking at home pages of sites like Facebook and Twitter, they don't do that (twitter.com will display in the visitor's locale, which is stored in a cookie). Beside, a url like `twitter.com?locale=en` is kind of ugly...

What are my options if I want to use `Cache-Control`, set the locale using `HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE` **AND** have one single URL, like Twitter and Facebook do?